# Ubuntu 21.10 Chrome wont open

Tags: google-chrome

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 21.10 I cant get google chrome to start.
When I double click it, nothing happens.
When I run `google-chrome` as non root user I get this output-

```
chrome_crashpad_handler: --database is required
Try 'chrome_crashpad_handler --help' for more information.
```

using --database does not work either.

When I run `google-chrome` as root user I get this output-

```
[6196:6196:0418/092051.706344:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

If I add `--no-sandbox` it opens the "Welcome to Google-Chrome" tab but its blank. Also I need it to work with non root permissions as I am planning to start chrome in kiosk mode.

I have tried:

- Re installing Chrome, even through terminal
- Deleting chrome configuration files
- Re installing Ubuntu!

This has never happened to me, even on other Ubuntu installations on the same laptop model I am using.
Any advice?

Comment: Having run google-chrome as root previously may exactly have been what is causing your issue. Never run graphical programs as root unless they are designed for that. Delete your google chrome profile: it will solve the issue

Comment: I have tried opening it the GUI way before trying do in terminal. I did delete my profile again but it does not change anything.

Comment: Where was the profile located?

Comment: ~/.config/google-chrome

Comment: Weird, I deleted the profile for the 4th time and only now it did work. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I was pretty sure something went wrong deleting your profiles previous times.

Comment: The problem could be as simple as disk with $HOME is full!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, deleting `~/.config/google-chrome` worked.

Here's what you should type to delete you profile and make chrome works again (hopefully):

```bash
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the ~/.config/chromium was symlinked to the /dev/null for some unknown reason and I've got the this error:

```
$ chromium                                                                                                                             
chrome_crashpad_handler: --database is required                                                                                                                              
Try 'chrome_crashpad_handler --help' for more information.                                                                                                                   
[134448:134448:1020/095648.288463:ERROR:socket.cc(120)] recvmsg: The connection was terminated by the remote party (104)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core made)
```